# Select com Join, em Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, select, join

Estou com uma dúvida em um select com o uso de join em codeigniter, segue:

Tenho 2 tabelas.

```
tabela jogo
id | id_time1 | id_time2
99 |    1     |    2

tabela time
id | time
1  | Real
2  | Barcelona
```

Quero retornar os times para montar um confronto: Real x Barcelona

Meu select está assim:

```
$this->db->select('jogo.*, time.time AS time_nome1, time.time AS time_nome2');
$this->db->from('jogo');   
$this->db->join('time', 'time.id = jogo.id_time1');
```

Desta forma eu consigo retornar o time 1 mas não o time 2 ou vice e versa, mudando o join para **jogo.id_time2**

Como eu faço com o join para retornar os dois times?

Desde já obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou um `Join`, segue o código:

```
$this->db->select('jogo.*, t1.time AS time_nome1, t2.time AS time_nome2');
$this->db->from('jogo');
$this->db->join('time as t1', 't1.id = jogo.id_time1');
$this->db->join('time as t2', 't2.id = jogo.id_time2');
```

Os nomes dos times estão na mesma tabela, porém cada time tem um ID, logo cada time é uma linha na tabela. Para trazer os dois ao mesmo tempo, você tem que fazer dois inner joins. Observe que utilizei t1 e t2 como alias e referenciei esses alias no select (t1.time e t2.time). 
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Exatamente isso, deu certo.
Procurei por tudo e não tinha ideia que era tão simples assim.
Muito obrigado!